# Angular -using jsonPath

Tags: angular, jsonpath, jsonpath-plus

In my app I want to use json path.
I found this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus), but I cannot get it to work from my app.

Per the documentation I installed the library and put this line in my component:

```
import {JSONPath} from 'jsonpath-plus';
```

But I received an error when I tried to do this:

```
const blob = JSONPath(path, jsonData, null, null);
```

Error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonpath-plus/dist/index-es.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vm' in 'C:\urm\workspace-1.0.0.2-URM\esploro-web\src\main\ngapp\node_modules\jsonpath-plus\dist'
```

Any idea how to make it work?
Another way to use jsonPath using Angular?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

**ESM (Modern browsers) You may also use ES6 Module imports (for modern browsers):**

```
<script type="module">
import {JSONPath} from './node_modules/jsonpath-plus/dist/index-es.js';
const result = JSONPath({path: '...', json: ...});
</script>
```

**ESM (Bundlers) Or if you are bundling your JavaScript (e.g., with Rollup), just use:**

```
import {JSONPath} from 'jsonpath-plus';
 
const result = JSONPath({path: '...', json});
```

Try using first one. I guess that will help.

Comment: I also tried putting this import in my component "import {JSONPath} from '/node_modules/jsonpath-plus/dist/index-es.js';" it recognize my import but I still get this error..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is an open issue about it, still open..

https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath/issues/129